# Store Google Map once it loads in android device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Unfortunately i have not found any answer to store the Google map in SO.

I'm currently working in a Map application which will show user's friends locations. But when I'm clicking on a new friend it loads the map again and consumes resource.

Is there any way to store the map once it loads and not go to the Map Server again when required. So I can just put the new location values when required and it will use the stored map to show.

> I load the map in general way like below:

```
switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity())) {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
        mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (mapView != null) {
               map = mapView.getMap();
               map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
               map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
               CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15);
               map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:

            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:

            break;
```

EDIT: `Or Is there any way to prevent the map to loads again and again?`

Comment: please don't down vote my question. I tried my best to make understand to others. if any help then it will must appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google map view should already cache the map tiles, so if you're seeing lag then make sure you aren't doing any unnecessary work before displaying the map.

If you want a static map of a single coordinate, look into [Google Maps Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/). Your app could fetch the image once, cache it itself, then display it whenever the user has to see it. When the user changes their location (I'm assuming it's not often) then refetch the static map.

As of January 2017 the link should be https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Comment: Thanks tar. your Static Map idea helped me to resolve my problem.Good answer.accepted with upvote.

Comment: @tar this is a great answer for web pages. Thank you.
For mobile apps this would be a workaround that might take quite a bit of work though. You would need to create a web view in place of a map view and then build the html to pass into it and have it load up.
I am investigating a way to do this within the maps sdk for android. **There is a way via a setting but my app is still racking up major costs with this method. If I find a way I will post another answer here for anyone else looking for that side of it.